# Tailwind autocomplete in WebStorm not working even after the config file for Tailwind 3.3.2 using with Vite-react4.3.2 and three.js

Tags: autocomplete, tailwind-css, webstorm, intellisense, vite-reactjs

In `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Framework | Style sheets` the IDE is not showing Tailwind as an option. It shows no documentation on <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd>. I'm using Tailwind with Vite, React and three.js.

[image]

[image]

No Tailwind option:

[image]

And here is the dependencies list as well:

[image]

Comment: *"No Tailwind option:"* I see only Stylelint. Where is another standard `Dialects` option? There is a chance that you simply have those plugins disabled for some reason. Please check what you have at `Settings/Preferences | Plugins` -- just type `css` in the search box there to filter the plugins list.

Comment: all tailwind plugins are installed and enbled still same